# How much can we "reduce" this polynomial division?

Tags: polynomials, intuition, divisibility

Let's say we start with a univariate polynomial, $p(x)$:

$$p(x) = x^n-1$$

We can then divide by another polynomial; for instance $q(x)$.  For example, if $p(x) = x^6-1$ and $q(x) = x^2-x+1$ we have:

$$\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\frac{x^6-1}{x^2-x+1}=1+x-x^3-x^4$$

Here $q(x)$ has 2 roots, and the resulting division yields 4 terms with nonzero coefficients.  There are three numbers of interest here.  The degree of $p(x)$, which we can call $n$, the number of roots, and the number of nonzero terms.

I'm interested in finding the largest (or large) ratios of $n$:(roots + nonzero terms).  In the case of the above example, the ratio is $n=6$:(2 **complex** roots + 4 terms).  **Can we do better?**  In other words, can we find a greater $n$ with less roots and resulting terms?

If we can do better, what are $p(x)$ and $q(x)$?

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

**$p(x)$ is always $x^n-1$.**

**I'm counting the number of complex roots.**

Answer (score 1):

How about $x^8-1$, which we can divide by $x^4+1$ to get $x^4-1$?  We have $n=8$, $4$ complex roots, and $2$ non-zero terms.  Clearly the approach works for any $n$ a multiple of $2$ with ratio $\frac n{\frac n2+2}=\frac {2n}{n+4}$

Added:  We can also do $x^{(2m)^2}-1$ and divide by $x^{2m}+1$, giving $x^{4m^2-2m}-x^{4m^2-4m}+x^{4m^2-6m}\dots-1$.  This will give $n=4m^2, 2m$ roots and $2m+1$ non-zero terms, for a ratio of $\frac {4m^2}{4m+1}$ which get arbitrarily large with $m$.  By considering the degrees, we can show this is optimal

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I thought that $x^4+1$ has 4 **complex** roots.

Comment: @MattGroff:  It does.  I didn't know whether you meant real or complex roots.

Comment: Sorry - I've edited the question.

Comment: @MattGroff:  It is still an improvement that can get us close to a ratio of $2$

Comment: I believe there's an error in your calculations.  $x^{m^2}-1$ should be $x^{2m}-1$.  That would seem to change the ratio...  For example, try $\frac{x^6-1}{x^3-1}$ which divides evenly, versus $\frac{x^9-1}{x^3-1}$, which doesn't.

Comment: @MattGroff: I needed +1 in the denominator, but then need $m$ to be even to come out even.  See the edit